# sails.js with passport-twitter

Tags: node.js, express, sails.js, passport.js, passport-twitter

I am integrating [`passport`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport) with [`sails`](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails).

While google and facebook is working fine in my application I struggle with twitter authentication! When clicking on the 'login with twitter' button there is an error thrown wich says: `Error: OAuthStrategy requires session support. Did you forget app.use(express.session(...))?`

I read [here](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter/issues/43) that sessions are necessary for twitter authentication to work. I made sure my app has sessions activated!

I testet [`passport-twitter`](https://github.com/jaredhanson/passport-twitter) with a simple express app (without sails) to make sure the module is working and my twitter credentials are intact.

**I am assuming sails sessions are different to express sessions? Is sails changing the way sessions work? Any advice on how to solve this?**

---

EDIT: Added some more info as requested in the comments:

Sails Version: 0.9.13

**UserController.js:**

```
...
twitter: function(res, req) {
    passport.authenticate('twitter', {failureRedirect: '/login'}, function(err, user, info) {
      return console.log(err, user, info);
    })(req, res);
  }
...
```

**config/passport.js:**

```
...
passport.use(new TwitterStrategy({
    consumerKey: '**************',
    consumerSecret: '********************',
    callbackURL: "http://127.0.0.1:1337/auth/twitter/callback"
  },
  function(token, tokenSecret, profile, done){
    process.nextTick(function() {
      console.log(profile);
    });
  }
));
...
```

Comment: Where do you call `authenticate` from?

Comment: From the UserController

Comment: Could you publish a snippet? Also, which Sails version?

Comment: added more info.. thanks for help

Comment: Hmm, all looks good, but I have a feeling that it has something to do with the Express middleware loading order. Can you show the middleware config?

Comment: That sounds plausible! I am not sure how to influence the order of config files being loaded with sails! All I did was putting passport.js (where I also configured passport.session and passport.initialize) into the /config folder. Sails loads it with all the other config files.

Comment: (1) Are you serializing and deserializing the user in passport.js?  Someplace else?  If not at all...that's your problem.  (2) Did you edit config/session.js at all to use a different session store, like redis?  If so, can you post your changes?

Comment: @Sven You should have something like `app.use(passport.initialize());` and `app.use(passport.session());` where `app` is, basically, Express. Could you show this part of your `config/passport.js`?

Comment: @bredikhin: sails is taking care of that express stuff

Comment: @Matt Bakaitis: I am serializing and deserializing in passport.js! I didn't edit session.js! Might that be the problem? Do I need some session store other than memory?

Comment: You can use the memory session store as you develop and should be fine.  I guess I'd ask: are sessions working at all?  How did you confirm they work?  Are you using another passport strategy that's doing fine while the twitter strategy is failing?

Comment: @MattBakaitis Facebook, Google and local strategies are working fine!

Comment: @AJcodez: I didn't figure it out. Sry :-/

Answer (score 2):

Did you try sails-generate-auth with sails 0.10? It makes life easier from my point of view: https://www.npmjs.org/package/sails-generate-auth

Answer (score 0):

check out one example how to do Twitter auth (google, facebook, github are there as well):
https://github.com/stefanbuck/sails-social-auth-example

Answer (score 0):

I recommend that you don't spend time integrating this yourself. There are a number of existing solutions. The [**official documentation**](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth) lists several options:

> - [sails-auth](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-auth): Passport-based Authentication Extension, including Basic Auth
> - [sails-permissions](https://github.com/tjwebb/sails-permissions): Permissions and Entitlements system for sails.js: supports user authentication with passport.js, role-based
>     permissioning, object ownership, and row-level security.
> - [sails-generate-auth](https://github.com/kasperisager/sails-generate-auth): Generate a Passport.js authentication layer for your Sails app